# Why this same-origin policy error on same domain?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy

Shortly before releasing a new website we have found computers, where the same origin policy restricts access to pages on the same, well origin, or domain. This is the site: http://blanc-encens.com/.

To make it all worse, if it does not work immediately, after some reloads it works!!

Could you please tell me theoretically why this could happen, <strike>or if you are one of the chosen few, where it does not work inspect the problem</strike>? Edit: I set the header manually to "*" now!

The Chrome console error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://blanc-encens.com/profile?ajax=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.blanc-encens.com' is therefore not allowed access. profile:1 0 core.js:271
```

In Chrome there are no `Response Headers` in the network tab on not working machines.

My code:

```
var hyper = {
    init : function() {
        this.content($('.navigation a').not('.follow a'));
        this.pop();
    },

    content : function(obj) {
        obj.on('click', function(e){
            var thisUrl = $(this).attr('href');
                thisalt = $(this).attr('alt');
            hyper.load(thisUrl);
            e.preventDefault;
            window.history.pushState(null, thisalt, thisUrl);
            document.title = thisalt;
        });
    },

    pop : function() {
        window.onpopstate  = function() {
            hyper.load(location.pathname);
        };

    },

    load : function(page) {
        page = page == '/' ? '/start' : page;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: page, 
            data: {ajax : 1},
            success: function(data) {
            $('.content').empty().append(data);
            }
        });
    }
};
hyper.init();
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you have any code that switches from `blanc-encense.com` to `www.blanc-encens.com`? As far as the browser is concerned, they're different domains.

Comment: @Barmar That sounds promising. But the real hard thing to throw your head against the wall is, that after some reloads the thing works everywhere well!!!

Comment: script caching maybe?

Comment: @KevinB How is that done? Or undone? ;) Do you mean to set `$.ajax` to `cache: false`?

Comment: No, i was referring to the previous comment, where you said it is now working. If it's working now and you didn't change anything, either your javascript was cached, or you have a race condition. ajax cache likely has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @KevinB Hmm, ok, what difference makes the caching of the javascript? The jquery works fine until the point where it makes the request! How to avoid a race condition here, this is where some request is made before some other function finished, if I understand right?!? Thanks!!

Comment: A race condition is when you have two things that must finish in a specific order, but sometimes finish in the wrong order and sometimes in the right order, resulting in it working sometimes and not working other times when performing identical tasks.

Comment: @KevinB Ok, you got me seconds before i saved my edited answer here ;) So where could this race condition be under these circumstances?

Comment: I don't see any at the moment.

Comment: @KevinB So the script caching again, where could that be?

Comment: @KevinB Kevin you must charge him for providing private tut :)

Comment: @thenewseattle Hehe, yeah, I would call that race condition demonic or an electron which is stuck in the pipeline between two hot spots. ;)

Comment: script caching is somewhat difficult to test for, it's easy to resolve by simply changing the url to the script each time you save it, for example `myscript.js?_=1` or `myscript.js?_=1.0.0`, or you can Ctrl+F5 to refresh without cache, or even completely close the browser and re-open it.

Comment: @KevinB Haaii, I completely loose my track here. Where do I save the script manually here? ;)

Comment: i mean, when you save it in your editor. YOu make a change to it, then in your html just change the url to the script to include a random url param.

Comment: @KevinB I do not think that is the problem here either. The user goes onto the site the first time and after some refreshes it works. That means somehow the script needs to be cached first?!? And how can that provoke a cross-domain error?

Comment: @KevinB Are you  t h a t  Kevin B? http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajax-cross-domain-call-ok-202-but-still-getting-firebug-jquery-js-error. Heaven, you gotta be able to help me!! :D I set on `$.ajax` the `crossDomain: true`. Will that be of any help? ;)

Comment: Yes, it is. `crossDomain: true` isn't needed 99% of the time.

Comment: What is the thought process behind using this conditional? `var thisUrl = location.host == 'blanc-encens.com' ? '/test' + $(this).attr('href') : $(this).attr('href');` Which ajax request in your code is having problems?

Comment: @KevinB This line is for making it work on the production server and on my local machine, which is simply http://blanc. The ajax request in the `load` function is having problems. By "which" you mean which call is having problems? Could it be that the pushState is causing something? There are two other ajax request in the whole script. One for pulling the big images when you click on a profile image and one for the contact form!

Comment: It sounds like you aren't making a cross-domain request at all, and yet you are getting a cross-domain error. Are you sure your href value isn't the full url to your test server?

Comment: what does `console.log(thisUrl)` and `console.log(location.href)` give you?

Comment: @KevinB No, I am not making a cross-domain request at all!! Does the site work on your machine? If so, the values cannot be wrong. ;) I cannot log these since I have no machine under my control where it goes wrong... but here an anchor snippet `<li><a alt="OLIVER RUUGER" href="/oliverruuger">OLIVER RUUGER</a></li>'.

Comment: Of course I could leave the trailing slash away, so it is dynamically to the `URI`I am in. Should I try? I'll do!! Hehe.

Comment: @KevinB I deleted the trailing slashes and it seems to work, if you use www.blanc-encens.com, but not when you use blanc-encens.com!?! Do you think it is a good idea to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the `.htaccess`?

Comment: `www.blanc-encens.com` and `blanc-encens.com` are two different origins. If you request `www.blanc-encens.com` from `blanc-encens.com` you will have a same origin issue.

Comment: @KevinB No, not like this. If somebody goes onto `blanc-encens.com` he got sometimes the trouble, on `www.blanc-encens.com` reportedly not!?! Greetings!

Comment: Correct, because you're hardcoding www.blanc-encens.com in the ajax url. Requesting from `www.blanc-encens.com` while currently browsing `blanc-encens.com` will result in a cross-origin error.

Comment: @KevinB Ah, I see what you mean. Firstly I did not only delete the trailing slash, I also deleted the code you are referring to, because I do not need him anymore. Still this problem occurs without www. Secondly the problem disappears after some reloads, which cannot be, but reportedly is a safe way to overcome the problem, what can you say?

Comment: does it ever come back, after it goes away?

Comment: @KevinB Actually I never hardcoded www.blanc-encens.com, I had blanc-encens.com in the IF (ternary) clause, this does not set any domain...

Comment: @KevinB Never heard of coming back, that's the strange thing. :)

Comment: well, if it was part of the href of the anchor tag that initiated the event, it would be pulled in.

Comment: @KevinB Well I see. It wasn't. :/

Comment: @KevinB I changed so far the trailing slash, set `Access Allow-Origin` header to `"*"` and made a loop in the `Ajax` `error:` by calling the `load` method again, since the failure goes away when reloaded several times. But I want to get E-mails in the future when something gets wrong, perhaps even taking the `*` header away before. So how do I get the error message from the console output, i mean a detailed error message on error of the `AJAX` call? Something like remote debugging? I need to get the request header at best?!?

Comment: @KevinB I saw after repeated staring on the error message, that the `URL` was wrong. It should have been blanc-encens.com/test/profile?ajax=1. Could it really be, that javascript made an error, or the race condition was here in `var thisUrl = location.host == 'blanc-encens.com' ? '/test' + $(this).attr('href') : $(this).attr('href');`?  Thank you! P.S.: If this is the source for the mistaken URL, how could this be a same-origin error then, it is still the same domain?!? 1

Comment: @Barmar Hey Barmar, I tried to answer the question with your help!! Thank you!!!

Comment: @KevinB Hey Kevin, I tried to answer the question with your great help!! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I come back now with what I think is the "race condition" in this case. Barmar hit the nail on the head on his first comment, thank you KevinB for sticking so long with me and sorting everything out for me. ;)

**The lines in the `.htaccess`**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blanc-encens\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://blanc-encens.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**The old lines in the Javascript**

```
var thisUrl = 
location.host == 'blanc-encens.com' 
? '/test' + $(this).attr('href') 
: $(this).attr('href');
```

- Now somebody gave out the link with `www` in front, which this script was obviously not prepared for.
- So the race condition must have been in the `.htaccess` not working already (anybody heard of that?), or not fast enough.
- When somebody opened the page, it always started of course, but on first click on a link the obvious confusion comes in.
- The `.htaccess` did not work first or fast enough, then somebody clicked on a link, the Javascript decided to have no `blanc-encens.com`; which you can see on the error-message, no `/test` in the URL.
- Then the `.htaccess` kicked in.
- Et voila, you tried to switch from `www` domain to without-`www` domain. Bumm, same-origin policy error. ;)